# Visual Code show Cannot find module warning for absolute import

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I using typescript and react and manage to do absolute import in VS Code by follow  this [link](https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/type-safe-es2015-module-import-path-aliasing-with-webpack-typescript-and-jest-fe461347e010), I followed all steps except step 2, and the code can be executed without an issue. But in the VS Code compiler it show warning `"Cannot find module"` like in the image, so is that a way to clear this warning?

[image]

This my **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",   
    "sourceMap":  true, 
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "custom": ["src/components/custom/"]
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: can you provide your `tsconfig.json` in the question?

Comment: @MarcoDaniels include tsconfig.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `tsconfig.json` if you add `*` in the `paths` key and value should fix it, something like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",   
    "sourceMap":  true, 
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "custom/*": ["src/components/custom/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

That should make the import pointing for all components under the folder `custom` and they can be imported as `custom/fileName`. And it should also auto-complete.

---

Edit:

To configure using Gatsby you can add the following in your `gatsby-node.js` file:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions }) => {
  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        'custom': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/custom/*'),
      },
    },
  })
}
```

Comment: I am using Gatsby. And although it supports TypeScript, there is no tsconfig.json

Comment: @KevinBurton I've updated the answer with a configuration for Gatsby. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. I was Googling around and found adding a d.ts file with
```
declare module '*.mp4'
declare module '*.jpg'
declare module '*.png'
```
Both work. Would you care to comment on this method?